# Route specific page to controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

If I have a page on my site (extension could be ".html", whatever:

http://tempuri.org/mypage.asp

I want this page to invoke a specific web api controller and action.  Can anyone help with configuring this in the route mapping?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can route a specific file type to an action of a controller.

Firstly, you have to add a handler in web.config (web.server/handlers node)

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Then, insert the following code in your `RegisterRoutes` function (it has to be before the default route)

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Special",
           url: "{page}.html",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

After doing so, all requests for .html files will be forwarded to the index action in the home controller.

Hope this helps.